# My action button keeps changing the size of a grid object

Tags: html, vue.js, vuetify.js

This is a simple problem possibly but I just recently started working with vuejs and veutify and added a grid system for a project management app I'm working on for school and when I add the button it distorts the bar. I made it into its own component and tried to nest it within the project bar

How I want it to look. This was before I nested the component https://gyazo.com/04ca8e62f32f2077d739dd9f7d6b55be

How it looks now
https://gyazo.com/919725a55ccec56e133b231404c18590

My Project Bar Code

```
         <!-- Need to do container -->
       <v-container fluid grid-list-md text-xs-center>
         <v-layout column>
          <v-flex>
           <v-card dark color="blue">
             <v-card-text class="px-0">Need to Do</v-card-text>
             <v-flex>
         <!-- Nested-->   <AddTask />
           </v-flex>
          < /v-card>           
         </v-flex>
       </v-layout>
    </v-container>
```

My Button Code

```
        <template>
         <v-dialog max-width="800px">
           <v-btn fab small color="cyan accent-2" bottom left block 
            absolute 
          slot="activator">
         <v-icon>add</v-icon>
         </v-btn>
            <v-card>
        <v-card-title>
            <h2>Add a Task or Project</h2>
        </v-card-title>
        <v-card-text>

        </v-card-text>
    </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
     </template>
```

Comment: Anyone know whats going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move `AddTask` between `<v-card-text class="px-0">`  use the below code for project bar codepen : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bZPxwW

```
<v-container fluid grid-list-md text-xs-center>
         <v-layout column>
          <v-flex>
           <v-card dark color="blue">
             <v-card-text class="px-0">Need to Do
 <!-- Nested-->   <AddTask />
</v-card-text>

          </v-card>           
         </v-flex>
       </v-layout>
    </v-container>
```